# Example for Webapps (ios & android)

Tags: android, ios, web-applications, iphone-web-app

I have an nice app idea and have to decide wether to code 2 native apps - android and ios or to code an webapp, which will speed up my development really much.

but after some research about Webapps (embeded in an WebView) i have one little Problem...
i cant find any examples for web apps.

Do someone know good examples for webapps? especially apps that with an android and ios version.

**CLARIFICATION (i think the above is a bit misleading):
I dont search for actual code or something like that. i only search for names of Apps which are developed with html/css/javascript (+ phonegap or anything) so i can download them and check how fast they are, how they look, if there are any differences to selfcoded native apps, and so on...**

thx for ur help

Comment: I have a very good exemple (with comments and all you need to understand) but only for ios.

Comment: sry, i think my initial question was a bit missleading - please have a look at the edit

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by 'web app'.

Apple WILL reject any application that is just a wrapper around a `UIWebView`, so it must contain some more native code than that. There are certain apps (f.x. [The Atlantic](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/atlantic-magazine-digital/id397599894?mt=8)) That are created with online technologies like [RareWire](http://rarewire.com), that allow them to include native UIs for web-based technologies.

So you have a few options:

1. A native app with a server supporting it for web content (most common)
2. A true web-app which is saved to the user's homepage in safari (second most common)
3. A `UIWebView`-based app, with native controls for certain things (maps, photos, GPS, etc.) (least common).

The fact is, apple is very strict on their guidelines for apps on their appstore, and what you are referring to doesn't exist in the wild (however, if you are looking for jailbreak apps, it's a totally different story).

Comment: but there must be some, if not many apps developed with tools like phonegap (see post above) - which i would call webapps

Comment: @jacksbox the thing is, tools like phone gap, appcellerator, and rare wire, all compile to a native app. They take elements in their HTML which can be converted to native controls and they do. That is their advantage over a web app in safari.

Comment: yes - but still i write the code in html/javascript - thats the whole point - i want to check out how fast these apps are, how they look, and so on...if they compile to native code or not doesnt matter